# How to display a PDF from ResponseEntity in controller method and display to JSP using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a pdf stored in my local and from my controller method i am trying to return it in the form of ResponseEntity
If i display directly the response from controller it works fine but my requirement it to embedd the pdf on a section of jsp on IE which is not working.

Below is the code:

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/cde")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() {
        // json => emp
       System.out.println("here");
        byte[] contents=null;
        // generate the file
        try{

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\abc.pdf");

         contents = Files.readAllBytes(path);
         System.out.println("CONTENTS"+contents);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String filename = "output.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;

}
```

JSP:

```
<a href="#" id="cde">Fetch pdf</a>
<div id="doc2"></div>
<script>
$( "#cde" ).click(function() {
alert('here');
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'cde', 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: ""
    ,

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, error, errorThrown){  
          alert(error);  
          alert(errorThrown);  
          },   
    success : function(data) {
     alert('success');
     alert(data);
     var obj = $('<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" border="2"></object>'); 
     obj.attr('data','data:application/pdf;base64,'+data);  

    $("#doc2").append(obj);   
    }
});
 });
</script>
```

The code is working on FIREFOX but not on IE

Comment: Can you please check at IE, is there any javascript console exception message?

Comment: no there is no exception

Comment: What is the version of IE?

Comment: Also can you try it with  var obj = $('<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" border="2"> </object>'); I put one extra whitespace before </object> tag.

Comment: nope not working, i am testing on IE8

Comment: What is the version of pdfobject.js? It should be at least 1.2 according to its documentation. PDFObject has been updated to version 1.2, and now supports Internet Explorer 9. It is also now available on GitHub. https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject

Comment: @user1767444Can you solve your problem?